# Trouble with xcoffins in TL2020

Tags: texlive, latex3, texlive-2020, xcoffins

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\NewCoffin\lcoffin
\NewCoffin\fcoffin
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\fbox{\parbox{.25\textwidth}{\begin{enumerate}\item This is a sentence which needs to be more than one-quarter the width of the text block and preferably wider than the whole width.\end{enumerate}}}

\SetVerticalCoffin\lcoffin{.25\textwidth}{\begin{enumerate}\item This is a sentence which needs to be more than one-quarter the width of the text block and preferably wider than the whole width.\end{enumerate}}%
\SetVerticalCoffin\fcoffin{.48\textwidth}{\centering [a]\par}%
\JoinCoffins\lcoffin[r,vc]\fcoffin[l,vc](.02\textwidth,0pt)%
\TypesetCoffin\lcoffin[T,l]\par%

\begin{enumerate}\item This is a sentence which needs to be more than one-quarter the width of the text block and preferably wider than the whole width.\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

With `pdflatex` from TL 2019, the result is as expected:

[image: 2019 output]

With `pdflatex` from TL 2020, the result is rather different:

[image: 2020 output]

The documentation for `xcoffins` indicates an update in October, but there's no list of changes/revisions and I can't see anything obviously different in the definition for vertical coffins.

Is this a bug or user error? If the latter, what's the mistake?

Comment: raised with the team, will get back to you....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug we will push out an update but as a workaround you can set `\linewidth` to the right value

```
\SetVerticalCoffin\lcoffin{.25\textwidth}{\linewidth=\hsize\begin{enumerate}
```

The difference in behaviour is hard to spot in the diffs or changelog as it is due to expl3 being loaded earlier in 2020 which had an unintended effect here as it is loaded before `\linewidth` is defined which caused it to use a definition intended for plain tex that doesn't set `\linewidth`.....

Comment: Thank-you. This is indeed preferable to my current workaround which goes `/usr/local/texlive/bin.2019/pdflatex ...` ;).